# how to show file in the shared download folder?

Tags: android

I have downloaded data as byte array from my own server and saved it at the shared download folder of the phone. But this file is not showing at the in-build download app of phone.

How to show file in-build download app?

I am using  the following code for it:

```
Java.IO.File storageDir = global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

Java.IO.File storageFile = new Java.IO.File (storageDir, filename);                 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (storageFile.ToString(), filebyte);
```

If possible how can i do it?

Note: `filename` is the name of the file and `filebyte` is the byte array of data.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to download the file via Android's [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)in order to make it appear in the Downloads app.

You have to build a DownloadManager.Request, than pass that to DownloadManager.enqueue().

Even if the file is from your own server, you will have to find a way to pass the url to the Request.